# Curl XML Image Decode

Tags: xml, curl, type-conversion

I am able to retrieve an image with an API and curl but I am getting the image encoded in XML.  I was wondering how I could convert the XML to a jpeg?

Here is what I am retrieving...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><d:LargeImage xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" m:type="Edm.Binary">/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgEASABIAAD/7gAOQWRvYmUAZIAAAAAB/9sAhAAMCAgICQgMCQkMEQsKCxEVDwwMDxUYExMVExMYEQwMDAwMDBEMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMAQ0LCw0ODRAODhAUDg4OFBQODg4OFBEMDAwMDBERDAwMDAwMEQwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAz/wAARCADdASwDASIAAhEBAxEB/90ABAAT/8QBPwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAwABAgQFBgcICQoLAQABBQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAABAAIDBAUGBwgJCgsQAAEEAQMCBAIFBwYIBQMMMwEAAhEDBCESMQVBUWETInGBMgYUkaGxQiMkFVLBYjM0coLRQwclklPw4fFjczUWorKDJkSTVGRFwqN0NhfSVeJl8rOEw9N14/NGJ5SkhbSVxNTk9KW1xdXl9VZmdoaWprbG1ub2N0dXZ3eHl6e3x9fn9xEAAgIBAgQEAwQFBgcHBgU1AQACEQMhMRIEQVFhcSITBTKBkRShsUIjwVLR8DMkYuFygpJDUxVjczTxJQYWorKDByY1wtJEk1SjF2RFVTZ0ZeLys4TD03Xj80aUpIW0lcTU5PSltcXV5fVWZnaGlqa2xtbm9ic3R1dnd4eXp7fH/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwD0vqPU8LpmMcnMsFdY0Hckn6LGN/Oe5c+/629VvO7B6Y1lPa3LtFZieXVMa/Z/nqx9ZWF+XjkBpcxpLHvG4MJ+lYyo+x137r3/AEFQFNPNhNz+77TuP/kW/wBhqSnRZ9YMy2qx1bMZtgcRWHWyCBpNnp7vS3/S/PUP251wRNWDrz+sO/8ASaqYD6cjIDLWurxyDttkcg7drmfmrVs6FW5u7HsB8JH/AH5qCmoOv9ZmHV4LdP8AuQTr+7oz/pKJ+sHWg6G1YLtJJ+0Fo/FiHkYF+Of0rIH7w1H3qvsHgElNo/WTrYIH2XCg/nfa2x/1O5R/5y9fMfqWFr/3cb/cq2wDsEto8Alam1/zl6//ANwsP/2LYpD6ydciTh4nwGWxU9rfAfclsZ+6PuStTd/5x9Z2gnDxQddPtdfy/wA5Rd9aOrtJ/U8TaIhxzKhM/NVNjP3R9yW1n7o+4JWpun6zdREE1YQBMEnLbp/0Ux+tWaHRswS3945jAf8AN2uVLaz90fcExfWPBK1N3/nXm6e3p/mPtgkf+B7Uh9a83aTHTw7s37WP+q9NZ5urH+5QOVVOpSU6Y+tWaXQR08D94ZYM/BuxGZ9Y8xxiMJ/f2Xk/L6CxPtEuY6sOJY4HRpOnfhq1a8xltbq7K7tjxBBY6J+aSkjvrLnjQVYm7u3136D/ALYTt+sXV3D24mOf+vWfxx1gu6RfsDGvrAkxvLxAnSf0b1dxKaunta6Ptp1cRQC4B39W700VN6z60dQrJDqcFpBAh+WGnX+vUFAfW3N1mjCkeGazX/oLJzLsnMy67bKbGU1Hc2t7TJd+boA5vtUvtDR9JhHxEflQU6o+tubs3GnBDp+h9uZP+d6e1RP1vzAYGPhu8/t1QEf2m7lmDJpPgiC2g/u/MJWpvD6455iMPFPcxnUH+KkPrd1OJ/ZtRPgM3H/9KLOPpkyA0j4BO1lR5rafkErU6B+t3VNI6XXr/wB3MbT/AMFUmfWzqL5nApbBjXMpj79yo+jR3rZ/mhOaaDzWwxx7Qlam/wD86eoR/QaQfA5lH/kkv+dOdruwqB4H7bRB/wCks/0KP9Ez/NH9yb0Kf9Gz/NCVqdF31symxGNjGfHNoGv3px9bSSG7cMEmCPtlRiVm+jV2Y0fIJvSr/cb9wStTrv8ArJkta92zDhgkD7W3XyJ2bWf2lSf9cOols1UYAP8AKz6j9+1VfSpaJ9NgA/kj+5XcXo2TkgOFTWMP5zxH/RjckpHi/WbrF90WXdLprB+gy313kf1mXVsatCrrvVS4E4LLqS7aXVXN3AT7X6/ont2fS/S/o1Vz+lYHT6Ddn5dFFY/fbz/VbO9/9lqyMB/Tc6j7TiVmtm4ta7YaX+389u3a7Y76THJKe1xOo42USxji21v0qn6OH/km/wApitLj6r8mu2sl5uY1wILv5xuv0mWj6f8AVsXXz7Z8kVP/0O4+sI/TVH+SfyrJWv8AWMHfSR4FY0lBS2wtcXVPdW487Tof6zDurf8A2mI+P1DMxjzp+8zT/Oqef/Pdn/W0GUpSU7eP15j2xc0Pb+cRyB/Krch5f7DsrN7bxjmYPJEn+R/5FY8CQ4aOHBHKFax1ji5zmmexqYf+++5JS+J1LBzbcivEsNhxXhlstLdTO1zd/wCb7XKxKo1irFbtaYGsNaGtGpk+yprGprMtwGpDPI6n/NCSm8XgclDN7BwZWXbmu/NBJ8X/APkG/wDklVstyLDq4x4DQf8ARSU7T82ln0ngfifwQ3dRrM7Q533ALNow7n6taY8Ver6daRzHj3SUt9vc4wGAHz1R67WmC4ifBRGFTX/OWfeRP4SnjEadNzj5ApKbDLMcc7fmP71P9o4dY1ta34ED8ipl9PAo3f1inabz/NUMb4aJKTWdbwxw57z/ACQ4/kCCeq79a8TJtnQFtLzP/RUzj9TsEBzWDnTTj4K3SzrAaJvEjg7e37sb/ckpznZ2QOen5AHm1jf+jZYxycvyNu63DtpadQ5+yCP5JZY9XD0PHfrZi12Oc4utf6rmF8/yW1vaxWH9OdU1rOkhmAIh8Hdu/wA9u1JTkh8iWsMeI/2J/WeO7x8yiv6R1VtpuL2WO4neIP8AZ2sUHVdUZzSx/wACP++lJTA5Dzy4n46/9Uo+p4hp+Q/77CTrrm6W4n3EqPr4Z0fU+v5T/wCRSUr1G92D5Ej8u5IZG3QFzfjDv/IpxVhWfQuAJ7Olv5U7unWxuY7cPEa/9Skpk3NcPzg78EVuc384QqFmLkNnSUAi1h1BCSncZkVv4IUw4HusAXvadVYqzbB3keaSnYc5rWl7yGtaJc46AAd1ZwcbFyKW5N2S2mo67XAtfp+82zbsWN9srtYa7R7XCCDwQU4xaXmfa6Y1e0vOnEbn7f8AoJKdr9u9FxXGvpONZ1TJaYLqhLWn+XkWQxn/AFtUb/rF1fJuLDdXTVBmrBHrW7uzLMmzbjV/9uVoLcWssFdjnWVjUVmG1/8AbNQrrd/barDWNa0NYA0DgDQBJTT+z3WWG0sZU4822H7Rf/25ePRr/s02f8YrNdeyfc57j9JzjJPxKnCUJKSUDddW3xcB+K6+NIXK9PbuzqR/LH4Lq0lP/9HvPrF9Go/FYMLoPrCJqqPmVgnRBSySUqDnQJSUpzwBqYVd95cNDtb2Pc/1QhPyGWPLAeEtrjqfvKSlnOP5ntnl3Lj/AGkL0i46CVbqxXP1Og81dqxa2CY18UlObV059hBPCuMwcakAv5+8ol2ZXX7a/c78FQtvsedT8gkptWZtdYito07u/wDIhUbs+x873kj91vtH4IbgShOrKSl3Zj3ERpGnnATeu9zgA4n7yg2S1pLW6jlCqufu1KSnWo9TQkQrjMnYNRqqGPbuYCDqOVba6Qd3ySUnPVAzhuqdvVrnHbWwEntyfkqF/CjjPsbuA0kRPfnxSU67MnJfZXWX7DYXNBZWbNWD1LGthzfVeyv3OYz/AM+folduDaKq3tyBktsG4WNAaCOOAh9OYPtvSz/LyD91TGqz12muuwmtob6o3PHYun+d/k2fm7/z/wA9JTjZHULA4iFVdlvPZQsPvI81ApKZHJePFQdkTzr8QmMptqSmDn1nkBM2wM1Y4tPaCibGnsmOODxokpLX1K9uji24eDxr/nBWGZGFdDbAaHHgO1b/AJyznYzuyYC2vQHTwPCSnSu6Y1w3MhwPBCpWYb2HQfJExc11JAMtB57t/wA1azHVZNe7Q+KSnny1w5T132VcGR4LVyMCRLdfI/3rPsp2uIIg+BSU3MbLbbpw7uFba4FYTj6ZkGCtDEyvUbDuUlN9JM10hOkpudIbu6hV5SfuC6dc70Ns58+DCf4LoklP/9Lv/rBXuorcI3NcdT4Hlc+5dL1sTijyP8FzpCCkRcOENzDZ/V7+aM+oET3CkK4AHgkpo2YbLDLhqOCNCrGPhVV6wSfEmUYNCINElK0aJWfm5p3emJazu6OVcsl528DugPoHEaJKaTQXD26py1w5EIz8KojSWnxaYQj9oo0ePXq/6Q+SSmJCi5qI012DdWZ8W9wmICSmu9kjz7Kk+l+7cwaHkeC0XN0QXDVJSLHdYwy7TzK06rQ5sN5PflZdwEe7Udgi4by3UnbHaElOm3GdZydFJuC9h0J+CanIcQIOiOx1rzJdp4JKdHp2mZgT+Y67/pMY1Wuse+0+DRCXS6WmzHsJ91Zs08S8Nb/0dil11+13waip5jLpiyQqrg4cFEte5ziZUCAeSgpGLNYKI3VQ9MduU03NOrDHiNUlNgBTAQGWzzojscCkpfamNbTypFzWiSYCqvy3WEsxm7yOX8NH9pJS9tACFXk2Y7waiT4t7IjcEv8AdkPNjv3Ro1GGIwfQbCSnRxslt7JGh7hNfjV2thwlVKWuqcHDtytBrg4T4pKce7ADXydR2SFJEFvIWpawOCAKwkpWO8uaJVgKuxm15HblWBwkp1fq+0nJsd2DPylbyxfq8Nbnf1R+VbSSn//T9G61/Q/7S5udV0nWm7sI+TgVzRHcoFTKYBPgjFsiQgI9Lg5u3u38iSkTuU0olrY1QC5JSShu5pPmVJzEPGtAsNZ/P1b8e4VotSU1XMQXsKuOZKg5iSnMuxgTvb7Xj84f9+VZ1hLtr/bYOR2Pm1bDqQUG3GaeWhw8CkpzxMe7TwTO+CJbjOrk16s/0Z/74UIO8O3IPISUwc1V73GqtzwCdonaO6t/SQ7Gzp4pKRYfUC7aILW/nBy3sS1lkbViswhIc5pDT8gVrYTfTADdAkp6TpuljPn+RA647c58dhCbDuLdp7tSzm763E90VPMWMhA3HhXshkKhboUFLhTZPZDYUYOa0bnGAOSUlMw0HkT5qD3sq1LgAoh91+lI2M/0jh/1DUenDY33H3vPLnalJTVFdmW6Xy2ns3gu+P8AJV6uhrQGtAAHACMymOyKK0lIm1qYrRQxSaxJSH0xtKVB9gUskgM2NPudoos9oASUzKTWSUhqjQK2SUlNd7YsPkAEgkdSfE8poKSnf+rw/QWu8XAfcFrLL+r7SMNxPd5/gtRLop//1PSerCcJ3xC5qNV03UxOFZ8vyrnCNUFMISEtMt0I4UoTEJKTNLbW+Du4Ve2otPCkXNb9LTwUw8x++3w7/JJTRsaTxoRqCOQVYxs4O/R3e144PZym+lr9azPiO4+SqXUToQkp04BEjhMWrLryb6Dzub58q7T1Cl+lnsPj2SUm2eSg6tWGhrxuYQ4eIT+nKSmjZRuHCpXYG4+B7ELZNZHIUCwHskp5x9dmO6LBp+8OFe6XVTdke+CQJYD3K0LsVljS1wkFZVnSn1u9j/Z+6e3wSU6nUcUupkQHM1EmPlqqmPmY7QGve0O8CQsnOfg4NLr8kbi2BLyYknQfnOd/VapYvUcxzQem9FqAdqbsohu4/mv2ltlrv7TUlPV4m60t9Jpdu4ICnmZDammuz2P/AHXaFctjZX1mdYC99bBv1Yx9m1s8+myWtatN9vULbbRZWzPYxg9P1pDmk/T9Nx9X6SSmrlXsJMFUHO3O04QP2i8Z/wBkyKvTDphsSR/Vd+ctI4LnCa3CD3jVJTTDoO0Dc7sArNGG6xwfd7o4b+aPkrmN05rBMSe5Kusxw1JTWZQB2RW1KwKvJTFR5ISUgFakK0bZA4geKBbmY9Wk73eDeP8AOSUzDIQLslrfazU+KqX573nb2J0aOPmkwE6xqUlMwSTudyURgJTspJEu0CKIbxp590lMmtDBLufBDseXH8gSJlMkpjCeE4CdJT0PRGxgN83OP4rQVPpLduBV5gn8VcRU/wD/1fS+pf0K34fxXNnldPmNLsW1o1JaVy/dBS6SaWNLQ9zWb3BjS4gAuP0WiVrU9HrDd+TcA3uGkR/nlJTlAFWqemZtrdza4Hbd7VdbndJxnbMVnrPHLmDd99hWZ1HrL8twZTZYGM5qxzyf+GyNGf2WWJKWyGfZshlGQQy54Lq2zqQPpQQkQx/0hKqBt9jg+0hob9FjZJ/t2O+l/ZaxF3FJS1uG1w9p+SzcjptzH+pU5zT3b2K1RYQpeqDyElOLXdfS7Vxrd48f9JXq+qZlY9wFjfHn/qVafXj2CHNCrv6ZQTNTzWfI6fckpKOs1uEWMLD2IU2dTriTtePAHafx9qpnByW8Ftg+4obsW0fSqPy1SU6rOo4LtH7qz/Kbp/nM3NQrrsawlrTp2eDI/tD6azPSA8W/eExrB7pKa/V+k1XW4+Y9xfXRa0w1wLS536Jm4f2l0VLG1tAaANNVgWYu4sI1IsY4/J0rog0isHySU08XHL97vFxKt9KeTfkVnhgAHxKJhVEM0+KWCzZ1DLHZzWOHzBSU891XBryetVNIhzAbGkacLSqNFLYn1COzSPxefaqnV2D9rVsPetx+UhQbUB3P3pKdj7XhsaJMujUNBchu6hT+YyB+88gf9Fu5yzhWFJuPPDCfkkptftJgM/TI4a0EBRf1PJf9Bgb5lQbi2/ugDzUxifvPjyCSmrdbc/W60x4dlFrH2aVsMfvOV9tGMwzEnxKnvaPoiElNWrB26u58SrDa2M4EnzTl6aUlL1enflDEbbWMlzS9lTngOLRpLGFWLOlZ7NTUXf1SCszJ6fjZLt9tYe4cO4cI/dePc1WcPqnVunNDA85lDdBXcf0gHg2/6Tv+ub0lLvreww9pafAiFFa1P1i6LmkY2WRj3uH81fp/mW/QT5XRJHqYjt7TrsJ/6lySnISU3Vlj3Mdo5hhze4Pmo7UlPUYDduFSP5IVhDxxtorHg0fkREVP/9b1TlY2d0awPNmL7mnXZ3HwW0kkp4vOwLX7RdUZYdzQ4GJQAyzQejUyNNDaR/mPsXdRKiaqjyxp+QQU8V6W9oFzjY0cV/RrH/Wme3/P3ooLQIEAdgF132bHP+CZ/mhL7Ljf6Jn+aEqU8lKUhdZ9kxf9Ez/NCX2PF/0LP80JUp5JJdZ9iw/9Cz/NCb7Bh/6Fn3BKlPKSlK6v7Bhf6Bn3BL9n4P8AoGfcEqU8n6pHdOMhw7rqv2dg/wCgZ9yX7OwP9Az7kqU8r9pPcApjcw81tPyXV/s3A/0DPuS/Z2B/oGfcElPI2uqIaG1hri5oBHxWs5v6OPJWutYWLV059lVLWva+uCBqP0jAgQISUkxGwxMGBua54/Orj7nSpY/0QpvH6QnyRU4HVGtb1bGtc3cDTY2D/WY5IW1jitq0WVVXdbw2WtD27L9DqJArW3+zcD/QM+5BTyn2gjgAfJL7S/xXVfszA/0DPuS/ZnT/APQM+5KlPKes4903qHxXWfsvp/8AoGfcl+y+n/6Bn3JUp5Ten3rqv2Z0/wD0DPuS/ZnT/wDQM+5KlPLbkg5dT+zOn/6Bn3J/2bgf6Bn3JUp5bckTPK6n9nYP+gZ9yf8AZ+F/oGfclSnjMnEx8hm21jXt8HCVPAooxKX0Msy9j9fTdduqHkxvttZ/nLsP2fhf6Bn3JDAwhxSz7gkp5Sqqmt7nVM2usMvI1Lj4uWnhdNvve1z2Guoaku0J/qhbrKaWfQY1vwACmlSlgIEDgJ0kkVP/1/VUkkklKSSSSUpJJJJSkkkklKSSSSUpJJJJSkkkklKSSSSU1Oqs34NjfNp+5zXLM5C1eof0R/y/KsocJKS0cfNTd9N3wQ6DA+aIdXuSUiwmT1Op/wC614+/b/cttZGB/TR8CtdJSkkkklKSSSSUpJJJJSkkkklKSSSSUpJJJJSkkkklKSSSSU//0PVUkkklKSSSSUpJJJJSkkkklKSSSSUpJJJJSkkkklKSSSSU1uof0R/y/KsocLV6h/RH/L8qyhwkpnVx80TlzkOrj5ojfpOSUrB/po+BWusnB/po+BWskpSSSSSlJJJJKUkkkkpSSSSSlJJJJKUkkkkpSSSSSlJJJJKf/9H1VJJJJSkkkklKSSSSUpJJJJSkkkklKSSSSUpJJJJSkkkklNbqH9Es+X5VlDhavUP6JZ8vyrKbwkpnUfyojfpOQq/4ozPpOSUrC/prfgfyLWWThf05vwP5FrJKUkkkkpSSSSSlJJJJKUkkkkpSSSSSlJJJJKUkkkkpSSSSSn//0vVUkkklKSSSSUpJJJJSkkkklKSSSSUpJJJJSkkkklKSSSSU1uof0Sz5flWU3hafVLGV4Nj7HBrREk/ELEZl+oP0DHWDs6IH/SSU2Wc/NGZ9I/BUWPzCdK2jX95HrtyWkl1ROn5pBQUnw/6c34O/ItdYXTcuuzqTayCyyHHY4EGI7LdRUpJJJJSkkkklKSSSSUpJJJJSkkkklKSSSSUpJJJJSkkkklP/0/VUkkklKSSSSUpJJJJSkkkklKSSSSUpJJJJSkkkklKSSSSUiyqq7cd7LG7mxMHxHuCxm/RW3d/NP/qn8iyKqbXgbW88E6D8UlMGQEevk/BV2syzY5rcZ7mh20WAt2nx/O3e1W68e5ri2wBhI9oLhr4wkpfAqrfkOe4S6v6J8J0K0ln9O9t9rSdYGi0ElKSSSSUpJJJJSkkkklKSSSSUpJJJJSkkkklKSSSSUpJJJJT/AP/U9VSSSSUpJJJJSkkkklKSSSSUpJJJJSkkkklKSSSSUpJJJJSPIrNtL62mC4EA+a5XLy+oNBx73bNuhawFvHfdLnLrlVzP2ft/XPTjtvifl+ckp5Cq/ILyS59TG8O3Pk/AVp3ZGVaR6llhI+iS8kt/qk/RW47/AJu+cfyd0I+P+wNw9P0938uf+/oKan1dxMo5FmbkWPe3b6de+B3lxELoEzdsDbEdo4ToqUkkkkpSSSSSlJJJJKUkkkkpSSSSSlJJJJKUkkkkpSSSSSn/2Q==</d:LargeImage>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a base64 image.  You can decode with `base64 --decode` example:

```
# get the url | remove XML tags | decode base64 > write it to a file

curl  <YOUR_URL_HERE>  | sed -n '/^$/!{s/<[^>]*>//g;p;}' | base64 --decode > test.jpg
```

Comment: Worked perfect!   Thanks a million!